# The mysqli|mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: server

```
#sudo apt-get install php-mysqlnd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php-mysqlnd is a virtual package provided by:
  php7.1-mysql 7.1.2-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
  php5.6-mysql 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
  php7.0-mysql 7.0.16-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'php-mysqlnd' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone help me, how i solve this issue ?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`

Comment: #sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd

E: Unable to locate package php5-mysqlnd

Comment: use sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysqlnd or sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install one of the packages that contain your package.  Pick the latest:

Also, when installing a package, make sure your libraries are updated with these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install php7.0-mysql
```

Run these steps to purge and install PHPMyAdmin fresh:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge phpmyadmin
$ sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

When prompted to delete the PHPMyAdmin database, confirm to delete.  When prompt to create the PHPMyAdmin database, confirm to create.

**Update:**

This is the results of a version conflict.  Remove the pertinent files, especially the PHP packages and reinstall a consistent version.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55112/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-the-mysqlimysql-extension-is-missing-pleas).